# How can I update many rows with different values for the same column?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table with a column containing a path to a file. The path is an absolute path, and values for this column look like this: `C:\CI\Media\animal.jpg`.

The table looks like so, except there are many rows so editing by hand is not practical:

```
`+----+-----------------------------------+
| ID |               Path                |
+----+-----------------------------------+
|  1 | C:\CI\Media\sushi.jpg             |
|  2 | C:\CI\Media\animal.jpg            |
|  3 | C:\CI\Media\Tuscany Trip\pisa.png |
+----+-----------------------------------+`
```

Path is an nvarchar(260)

And what'd I'd like to do is run a query that will update each record so the path for each record replaces `C:\CI\` with `C:\CI\Net`, and end up with a table that looks like so:

```
`+----+---------------------------------------+
| ID |                 Path                  |
+----+---------------------------------------+
|  1 | C:\CI\Net\Media\sushi.jpg             |
|  2 | C:\CI\Net\Media\animal.jpg            |
|  3 | C:\CI\Net\Media\Tuscany Trip\pisa.png |
+----+---------------------------------------+`
```

Is there a way to format a query that will update every record, but update it based on the existing value (replace the `C:\CI` portion with `C:\CI\Net` for each record while maintaining the rest of the the value) instead of setting each column to the same value like a normal Update table set column = value ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gosh you almost wrote the code yourself.

```
Update YourTable
set path = replace(path, 'C:\CI', 'C:\CI\Net')
```

Comment: Beat me to it. +1 for typing speed.